Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'google_tag_manager' in Next.js 12
I'm trying to integrate the GTM snippet into a Next.js 12 app as explained in this guide: https://morganfeeney.com/guides/nextjs/how-to-integrate-google-tag-manager-with-nextjs.
In my _app.js file:
<AppThemeWrapper>
  {/* Script tag for GTM */}
  <Script id="gtm" strategy="afterInteractive">
    {`
      (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
      new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
      'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
      })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-******');
    `}
  </Script>
  <Component {...pageProps} />
</AppThemeWrapper>

And in _document.js underneath Head:
<body>
  <noscript
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: `<iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-******"
    height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>`,
    }}
  />
  <Main />
  <NextScript />
</body>

(Of course I've just hidden the GTM ID here)
Despite this, I'm getting the below syntax error, and I'm not sure why.

I understand that with Next.js 13 onwards you can use a native component to integrate GTM, but for now I need to get this working in Next.js 12. Any help would be appreciated.

You really have to work hard to get there. That global is deployed by GTM and used by it too. Sooo... Maybe something in your app kills unregistered globals or something? Well, first try to make sure the GTM container had been published at least once, so it's not just a brand new, empty and unpublished container. Also check your DOM, make a screenshot. I don't even know how you can manage to load GTM in such a way that it fails to deploy it's own core global. The noscript part is completely useless, may as well remove it.
